# Eulers Method Problem for oscillations

Tags: complex-numbers

In my classical mechanics book there is a relation made between:

$y=Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$ is equivalent $y=C\cos({x-\delta})$

Where A and B are complex, C is real and $\delta=\frac{\pi}{2}$
I have tried using euler's and trig substitutions to work out this equality but can not seem to get it. Can anyone explain how this is true?

Comment: I suspect there is something different in your book. Are you sure it is $B$ to power $-ix$?

Comment: My mistake. Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: Still the equality does not hold for arbitrary $A$, $B$, and $C$. I suspect something more is known about some of this values.

Comment: This was all that was given. http://imgur.com/0JMwOgW

Comment: The problem is D-6

Comment: This seems to be a mathematics question, not physics. There are no concepts or principles of physics involved here.

Comment: It is in a physics book and is used to describe oscillations.

Comment: This is certainly not true under your assumptions on $A$, $B$, $C$ and $\delta$. You can check it easily by starting transforming the cos into exponential and equaling the two relations.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE :) In physics books, there is a lot of math - so just stating "it appeared in a physics book" is not a sufficient reason :) I'd like for this question to be moved to math too (and I think you could get it cleared up yourself by writing the $\cos$ as exponentials ...)

Comment: Is it an actual equality or an equivalence between the two. For example, they both satisfy $\ddot y=-y$, right?

Answer (score 0):

First, your question is different from the book, there is nothing about $\delta=\pi/2$ in the book. Second, the statement in the book seems wrong: the second part is always real (if $x$ is real), whereas the first part is not necessarily real.